# StreamReader ReadLine() returns empty string, nothing added to list

Tags: c#, list, file, streamreader

I have a few problems reading from a file to a list.
The file content is like this:

```
[ROOM101]
that way this way no way all the way
[END]
[ROOM102]
all the way that way this way no way
[END]
[ROOM103]
no way all the way that way this way
[END]
```

And the method looks like this:

```
public static List<Room> ReadRooms(string path)
{
    List<Room> rooms = new List<Room>();
    StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(path);
    bool roomsLeft = true;
    char currentChar;
    string directions;
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

    while (roomsLeft) {
        currentChar = (char)reader.Read();
        if (currentChar == '[') {
            currentChar = (char)reader.Read();
            while (currentChar != ']') {
                builder.Append(currentChar);
                currentChar = (char)reader.Read();
            }
            if (builder.ToString() != "END") {
                directions = reader.ReadLine();
                rooms.Add(new Room(builder.ToString(), directions));
            }
        }
        if (reader.EndOfStream) {
            roomsLeft = false;
        }
    }
    reader.Close();

    return rooms;
}
```

It reads the first line fine, but `directions = ReadLine()` returns absolutely nothing, and nothing gets added to the list - shouldn't it jump to the next line and assign to `directions`?. The whole thing results in a `StackOverflowException`.

Comment: Because the last thing you read was the `]`, but not the newline.  Why not read in the lines and just check if the line starts with a `[` and ends with a `]` or if the it is "[END]" instead of trying to read one character at a time?

Comment: The code looks backwards.  How do you know that there are rooms left without reading file?  Normally you would loop on StreamReader until you get to null (End Of File).

Comment: I would recommend reading the new line in to a variable and then performing your logic on that line, because the stream reader will be reading on from your previous reads to the next new line char

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The specific issue you are referring to is because you read one character at at time and when you see the `]` you then do a `ReadLine`, but that will just read upto the newline that is after the `]` instead of the next line which is what you want.  But even if you fix that there are other issues in your code (like not clearing the `StringBuilder`) and it's better to just deal with lines instead of reading one character at a time.  Additionally instead of using a `StreamReader` that you need to clean up you can just use the handy `File.ReadLine` method.

```
public static List<Room> ReadRooms(string path)
{
    List<Room> rooms = new List<Room>();
    bool inRoom = false;
    StringBuilder directions = new StringBuilder();
    string name = null;
    foreach (var line in File.ReadLines(path))
    {
        if (inRoom)
        {
            if(line == "[END]")
            {
                rooms.Add(new Room(name, directions.ToString()));
                inRoom = false;
                directions.Clear();
            }
            else if (line.StartsWith("[") && line.EndsWith("]"))
            {
                // Found a start before the end, condiser throwing an 
                // exception, ignoring, or keep it as part of the directions.
            }
            else
            {
                directions.AppendLine(line);
            }
        }
        else
        { 
            if(line == "[END]")
            {
                // Found an end before a start either throw an exception or
                // just ignore this.
            }
            else if (line.StartsWith("[") && line.EndsWith("]"))
            {
                inRoom = true;
                name = line.Trim('[', ']');
            }
            else
            {
                // Consider throwing an exception here or just ignoring lines 
                // between [END] and the next room.
            }
        }
    }

    if (inRoom)
    {
        // Determine what to do if you had a room start, but no [END]
    }

    return rooms;
}
```

I've include a number of potential error cases that you'll need to decide how to handle.

Comment: Thank you. I've fixed my code based on your answer, and it works, and I understand why. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

After reading `]` character you assume that the reading the line is finished and think that `directions = reader.ReadLine();` will get you *that way this way no way all the way*

However, you haven't finished reading the line as there is the "newline" character after `]` and your reader does read that and returns an empty string.

Answer (score 1):

I've refactored your method into

```
public static List<Room> ReadRooms(string path)
{
    List<Room> rooms = new List<Room>();
    string roomName=String.Empty;
    StringBuilder directionsBuilder= new StringBuilder();

    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(path))
    { 
        while (!reader.EndOfStream)
        {
            string line = reader.ReadLine();
            if (line != null && line.StartsWith("[END]"))
            {
                rooms.Add(new Room(roomName, directionsBuilder.ToString()));
                directionsBuilder.Clear();
            }
            else if (line != null && line.StartsWith("["))
                roomName = line.Substring(1, line.Length - 2);
            else
                directionsBuilder.AppendLine(line);
        }
    }
    return rooms;
}
```

It should deal with multiple lines directions as well as room names like ROOM102 or APARTMENT201 etc.

Answer (score 0):

if  with in While is getting satisfied then after that next character is read which do not satisfy first if condition